# "get an illness" or "get illness", which one should I use in speaking?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I guess both "get illness" and "get an illness" mean ‘catch an illness’.

according to Ngram, "get an illness" seems more widely used in writing, how about speaking?

[image]

the weird thing is, "got cold" is more widely used than "got a cold".

[image]

I cannot even deduce a rule. should I put a "a/an" in speaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would rarely say "get (an) illness" this is not idiomatic.

We could either say "get ill" (or "fall ill") or "get a disease", though "catch a disease" is perhaps more likely.  If the type of disease is known then we would use that.

> John got ill while touring India. He had to spend three nights in Mumbai General Hospital. (I'd prefer "fell ill" here)
>
> You are very unlikely to get a disease from a toilet seat. There are more bacteria on the average chopping board than on a clean toilet seat.
>
> Jane caught measles as a child, so she had made sure her children were vaccinated, as she didn't want them to fall ill.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Though, I still cannot get a clear sense when to use "a". For example, "caught measles" or "caught a measles", which one would be more idiomatic?

Comment: It depends on the disease.  "measles" is plural   "caught measles" or "caught the measles", others are treated as non-count  "caught chickenpox". On the other hand we say "a cold". And we usually say "the flu".  So it depends, but there isn't a clear pattern.